# Preprocessing Mongoose documents right after querying

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose

## Abstract

Hi, I have two models `City` and `Country`:

```
var Country = new Schema({
    name: String,
    population: String
});

var City = new Schema({
    name: String,
    timeZone: { type: Number, min: -12, max: 12 },
    summerTime: Boolean,
    country: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Country'}
});
```

When I'm querying data from mongo using the following way:

```
function (request, response) {
    var CityModel = mongoose.model('City', City);

    CityModel.find().lean().populate('country').exec(function(err, docs){
        response.send(JSON.stringify(docs));
    });
}
```

But on client when I parse JSON, I get multiple instances of the same country:

```
var cities = $.get('/cities').then(function(citiesJson){
    var cities = JSON.parse(citiesJson);
    var washingtonIndex = ...;
    var californiaIndex = ...;
    var washington = cities[washingtonIndex];
    var california = cities[californiaIndex];

    washington.country.population = "300 000 000";
    california.country.population = "500 000 000";

    console.log([california.country.population, california.country.population]);
});
```

Resulting with two values `["300 000 000", "500 000 000"]` in the console.

## The problem

To prevent this kind of behaviour and preserve object references I'm doing [JSON.decycle](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js) before object serialization:

```
...
response.send(JSON.stringify(JSON.decycle(docs)));
...
```

It works better than it should be. As a result I get the following JSON on the client:

```
// City:
{
    name: "Bost",
        deleted: "0",
        country: {
        $ref: "$[0]["city"]["country"]"
    },
    lastModified: "2013-08-06T23:44:11.000Z",
    _id: {
        _bsontype: "ObjectID",
        id: "Rm1'"
    },
    approved: "1"
}
```

Notice the `_id` field which is getting serialized `by reference` so I don't get the actual ObjectId's string representation on the client, instead I'm getting some internal `mongo` representation of the id which is not usable on the client.

## The question

1) Is there a way to setup `per model` or `per schema` preprocessing for all queried documents so that I convert ObjectId's  into string

2) Probably there is some other more efficient way of dealing with this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You're using `populate` and then wondering why the same state/country is duplicated in the results when sending to the client?

Comment: And, are you saying using the `retrocycle` method of the json library you're using doesn't properly restore he structure?

Comment: No, I just want the `_id` property to be converted from `ObjectId` type to `String`, the retrocycle works great